# extracting only postcode and lsoa code - sparkql

Tags: r, sparql, rdf, semantic-web

I am trying to write some sparkql to extract postcode data and marching lsoa codes. 
what I have so far extracts all the url for both the postcodes and lsoa codes, when I would like just the last unit. How do i get just the last elements please?

```
query <- "PREFIX pc: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/postcode/>
      PREFIX geo: <http://opendatacommunities.org/def/geography#>
      SELECT * WHERE { 
      ?postcodeUnit
      a pc:PostcodeUnit;
      geo:lsoa ?lsoa .
      }
      limit 10"

   endpoint <- "http://opendatacommunities.org/sparql"
   resultList <- SPARQL(endpoint,query)
   head(resultList)
```

I am also concerned when i get this working, R studio will time out, do i need to run this from a web server? please

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the way URIs are generated is standard, you can just turn the results into strings and then take only the part that is needed:

```
PREFIX pc: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/postcode/>
PREFIX geo: <http://opendatacommunities.org/def/geography#>
SELECT ?postcode ?lsoa
WHERE { 
  ?URI_postcodeUnit
  a pc:PostcodeUnit;
  geo:lsoa ?URI_lsoa .
BIND (STRAFTER((STR(?URI_postcodeUnit)),"postcodeunit/") as ?postcode)
BIND (STRAFTER((STR(?URI_lsoa)),"lsoa/") as ?lsoa)
  }
  limit 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The code you have provided seems to throw errors and does not work

Comment: That brilliant thank you, i changed the " for ' and it worked great

Comment: I just tried it again, same as I posted it, and it works. Strange you had to change something.