# Extracting postcodes, LSOA codes and IMD - SPARQL

Tags: r, sparql

I am writing a code to extract the following data with [SPARQL](http://opendatacommunities.org/sparql-beta): POSTCODE, LSOA, and IMD (Index of Multiple Deprivation).

I managed to get close to this using two different calls but the approach isn't really what I am looking for because it requires additional matching in R.

The first call is described in [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35848462/extracting-only-postcode-and-lsoa-code-sparkql):

```
SELECT *
WHERE { 
    ?postcodeUnit a <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/postcode/PostcodeUnit>;
                  <http://opendatacommunities.org/def/geography#lsoa> ?lsoa .
} LIMIT 10
```

The second one is of my own attempt (I am a beginner user). It gets to call LSOA and IMD (although the labels are not human-readable, I guess there's no label)

```
SELECT *
WHERE { 
    ?obs <http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/communities/societal_wellbeing/imd/indices>
    <http://opendatacommunities.org/def/concept/general-concepts/imd/combineddeprivation>.
    ?obs <http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/geography/refArea> ?areauri .
    ?obs <http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/time/refPeriod> ?perioduri .
    ?obs <http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/communities/societal_wellbeing/imd/decObs> ?value .
} LIMIT 10
```

I could solve this issue to simply load these datasets into R and then match the postcodes, LSOA, and IMD there; however, I was wondering if it is possible to do it in one call.

Thanks for any help or clarification if what I am trying to do is possible.

Comment: Just combine the triple patterns of both queries. What's the problem here?

Comment: I think I am doing it wrong because if I combine my code into `WHERE {}` in the stackoverflow link and use `SELECT*`, then I end up with columns that don't match. So my IMD matches to postcodes from a different database I think.

Comment: Combine the triple patterns and add these two: `?areauri owl:sameAs ?sg. ?lsoa owl:sameAs ?sg .`

Comment: @StanislavKralin thank you. I was trying to do it but I ended up with a code `Unresolved prefixed name: owl:sameAs`, if I add `PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>` I get a timeout - I think the problem is simply that I don't know how to combine the triple patterns. I can edit the question to show my attempt to combine them if that's any help. Thank you.

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/aqfW6bR9) works for me on http://opendatacommunities.org/sparql-beta

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works for me too!

Comment: Hi, sorry to necromance this old topic but I'm trying to do the exact same thing and I'm not getting any results from the linked query. I'm largely unfamiliar with SPARQL so I'm struggling a bit to see where I'm going wrong. Should I be assigning a value to `?sg` somewhere? Any pointers would be gratefully received.