# Exporting data with SPARQL and filtering the result based on locally stored data

Tags: sparql

I am trying to match postcodes stored locally on my computer with postcodes resulting from the query sent to databases opendatacommunities.org and ordnancesurvey.co.uk.

Postcodes stored on my computer will follow standard format, for example:

```
IP3 
NR32 
IP8  
IP6  
IP18 
CB8  
Ip13 
IP31  
IP3  
IP11
```

*(Note: I've anonymized the postcodes by removing last three letters)*

What I've managed to do based on [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50396898/3223143) is the query below.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?lsoa_name ?area_name ?postcode ?period ?imd_dec
WHERE {
  ?obs <http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/communities/societal_wellbeing/imd/indices>
    <http://opendatacommunities.org/def/concept/general-concepts/imd/combineddeprivation>.
  ?obs <http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/geography/refArea> ?areauri .
  ?obs <http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/time/refPeriod> ?perioduri .
  ?obs <http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/communities/societal_wellbeing/imd/decObs> ?imd_dec .

  ?postcodeUnit a <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/postcode/PostcodeUnit>;
  <http://opendatacommunities.org/def/geography#lsoa> ?lsoa .

  ?areauri <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> ?sg .
  ?lsoa <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> ?sg .


  ?areauri rdfs:label ?lsoa_name .
  ?perioduri rdfs:label ?period .
  ?lsoa rdfs:label ?area_name.
  ?postcodeUnit rdfs:label ?postcode.
} LIMIT 10
```

The query returns ALL postcodes in England with the corresponding Index of Multiple Deprivation, and LSOAs, etc. The issue is that the result is so big that it's impossible to download it and save on my computer. Because I don't need the whole dataset of all postcodes but only sample that matches those stored locally on my computer (see the example above) I was thinking that by somehow matching the postcodes, I will be able to successfully reduce the amount of data, filter only relevant postcodes, and thus get a sample of data that I really need.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to get. You have only postcodes in a file and you want to complete information about them with the help of another database?

Comment: Add something like `FILTER (?postcode IN  ("TA21 9HB", "TA21 9DE", "TA21 9PQ"))` to your query.  Or `VALUES (?postcode) {("TA21 9HB") ("TA21 9DE") ("TA21 9PQ")}`.

Comment: @Gilles-AntoineNys I am trying to filter postcodes from the database based on postcodes stored locally. One way I was thinking of achieving that was to simply copy paste my postcodes directly into the query (although I do have roughly 1000 postcodes). So the output of the call is only postcodes (and other columns) I need (rather than for the whole of England).

Comment: @StanislavKralin your comment is pretty much the answer, can you post it as an answer?